# How to reference active document in Solidworks when there are multiple instances

Tags: visual-studio-2005, solidworks, vsta

I am using the following code in Solidworks 2017 Visual Studio Tools for Applications.  It's Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 Version 8.0.50727.42 running Microsoft Visual Basic 2005 and Microsoft .NET Framework Version 2.0.50727 SP2.

```
 Public Sub Reference_GetCurrentPartorAssembly(ByRef CurrentFile As SolidWorks.Interop.sldworks.ModelDoc2)

        CurrentFile = swApp.ActiveDoc

        If IsNothing(CurrentFile) Then Throw New Exception("Could not get reference to current part or assembly.")

    End Sub
```

Generally, the code works fine.  However, sometimes there are extra instances of Solidworks running which are listed under the "background processes" list in Windows Task Manager.  When that happens, my code throws the exception.  To get my code to execute without the exception, I have to find the stray solidworks background process and force kill it using Task Manager.

(I have no idea why these background versions of Solidworks show up.)

I did not find Solidworks' documentation on ActiveDoc to be very helpful: http://help.solidworks.com/2017/english/api/sldworksapi/solidworks.interop.sldworks~solidworks.interop.sldworks.isldworks~activedoc.html?verRedirect=1

My question is: how can I get a reference to the current document without having to force-kill those background processes?  I tried looking for other ways to get the reference to the active document but most code samples I have find all use ActiveDoc.

Comment: i would ask how you are connecting to the SldWorks object.  It sounds like you could be connecting to one of those background instances and there is no active doc to be had and thus it is coming back as null.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience multiple instances of solidworks can function perfectly fine, I don't think background version of solidwork would affect your main one. 
As I understand you are running a macro, not an addin, so make sure you are starting VSTS from your foreground version of solidworks. Maybe somehow your macro is executing against one of the background version that obviously has no activedoc.

Also I would take a look into backround instances, if you're not starting them - no reason for them to execute, try to take a note at which moment they appear to try to determine the cause.

Comment: As far as I can tell, I am starting the macro from the Foreground version.  I believe you may be right about the macro executing against the background version which has no activedoc.